# Pronunciation of "Blessed"

Tags: pronunciation

Is there any difference in meaning or usage when pronouncing "blessed" with two syllables rather than one syllable?

Two: **bles**-id `[blɛsəd]`

One: blest `[blɛst]`

Comment: Related question: [Are there any pairs of words like “beloved”/“belovèd”, “learned”/“learnèd” that maintain a semantic difference to the present day?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20997/are-there-any-pairs-of-words-like-beloved-beloved-learned-learned-that-m)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We reference the *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary*.

*[Blessed](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/blessed?q=blessed)* can be an adjective meaning *holy*, in which case it is pronounced with two syllables: *Blessed is the name of the Lord.*

*[Blessed](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bless_1?q=bless)* can also be the past tense of the verb *bless*, in which case it is pronounced with one syllable: *The priest blessed the bread.*

Comment: I like this answer. Totally agree.

Comment: I would also like to add that *blessed* can be pronounced as one syllable, even as adjective, e.g. `I am blessed`, `This college is blessed with so much talent`, etc.

Comment: There are other words that have two different forms like this: e.g. learned, wretched, dogged.

Comment: Jimi Oke - "is blessed" and "am blessed" in your examples are perfect verb forms, not adjectives.

Comment: @SingLow Perfect? You mean passive.

Answer (score 5):

One syllable is the present passive participle of *to bless*. Two syllables is a pure adjective. The adjective connotes an innate property of blessedness, but the passive participle indicates that it is a result of external action.

One syllable, "Blessed by the sermon on Sunday, the congregation shouted many amens."

Two syllables, "The preacher delivered a blessed message on Sunday."

Answer (score 3):

There's no real difference in meaning so far as I know.

Pronouncing the second syllable sounds archaic, I've only heard it used in recitations of old poetry or in clichés presumably derived from old literature of that sort.

Comment: Or hymns, of course.