# What does the grave accent mark on words mean?

Tags: orthography, poetry, silent-letters, diacritics

What exactly does the grave accent mean in English?

An example from Shakespeare’s [Sonnet 30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet_30):

> The sad account of fore-bemoanèd moan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any pairs of words like "beloved"/"belovèd", "learned"/"learnèd" that maintain a semantic difference to the present day?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20997/are-there-any-pairs-of-words-like-beloved-belov%c3%a8d-learned-learn%c3%a8d-that)

Answer (score 17):

[Wikipedia says it at least as well as I could have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#English):

> The grave accent, although not standardly applied to any English words, is sometimes used in poetry and song lyrics to indicate that a vowel usually silent is to be pronounced, in order to fit the rhythm or meter. Most often, it is applied to a word ending with -ed. For instance, the word *looked* is usually pronounced /ˈlʊkt/ as a single syllable, with the *e* silent; when written as *lookèd*, the *e* is pronounced: /ˈlʊk.ɨd/ *look-ed*). It can also be used in this capacity to distinguish certain pairs of identically spelled words like the past tense of learn, *learned* /ˈlɜrnd/, from the adjective *learnèd* /ˈlɜrn.ɨd/ (for example, "a very learnèd man").

Comment: +1 because this points out that it's _not standardly applied to any English words_ (I was just reading that same Wikipedia page before seeing that you posted a copy of it here).

Comment: Is /ɨ/ always the way the e ought to be pronounced?

Comment: @Mariano: Since by definition the "-èd" form is only used where no vowel is normally enunciated, it's a bit moot to argue about exactly how the "non-existent" sound should be pronounced. I think the "i" ("sit") form is transitional to being lost altogether, so you'll get that for *learned* because it still "sort of" exists in speech (though not in *learnt*). For many other words where a voiced vowel is unknown today, people will just vocalise it as "e" ("bed") because all they have to go on is the written form right in front of them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think most people would use the model of words where they normally pronounce '-ed', such as "wanted". The vowel would then be /ɨ/, /ə/ or /ɛ/ according to dialect.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I don't follow that. I normally say "wantid", but if I read a [poetic?] "wantèd" – which I'm not sure I ever have – I'd probably hear it in my "mind's ear" as "-ed" rather than "-id". I don't know if my being familiar with the accent in its native French habitat makes any difference to how I read/imagine hearing it.

Answer (score 7):

This line is from Shakespeare's [Sonnet 30](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet_30).  Shakespearean [sonnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnet) are 14 lines of iambic pentameter, so each line needs ten syllables. If the *-èd* was not pronounced separately then there would only be nine in this line, which would break the metre.  The grave accent is a help to the reader.

Incidentally, it is not stressed here.

A line earlier in the same sonnet is

> And moan the expense of many a vanish'd sight

where the apostrophe is a help to the reader not to pronounce the *-ed* separately.

Answer (score 1):

Guess: it means you place more emphasis here than usual. As in, "beh-MOAN'd" vs "beh-MOAN-ED".

(Thanks to commenter for keeping me honest).

Comment: Isn't it beh-MOAN?

Comment: Yeah, of course you're right. Not thinking.