# Pronunciation of 'dogged'

Tags: pronunciation

What's the correct way to pronounce 'dogged' ("He was dogged"/"dogged pursuit")? Is the 'e' silent or a schwa? Is it the same for the past of 'to dog' and for the adjective?

(What I tried so far: I asked Google translate to pronoune "He was dogged" and the e was silent; I looked it up in Merriam Webster's and it says the e is a schwa, but only for the adjective... I trust Merriam Webster's more than Google, but I still can't rule out that maybe the adjective is different than the past tense of the verb...)

Comment: Depends on the context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any pairs of words like "beloved"/"belovèd", "learned"/"learnèd" that maintain a semantic difference to the present day?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20997/are-there-any-pairs-of-words-like-beloved-belov%c3%a8d-learned-learn%c3%a8d-that)