# When to pronounce 'beloved' in 2 syllables vs 3 syllables

Tags: pronunciation, syllables

I've heard this pronounced as two syllables: be-loved.  And as three syllables: be-lov-ed.

Is only one correct?  If not, what cases require each use?

Comment: Good question. Since orthography doesn't distinguish, we have to pay attention to actual speech, and that's troublesome as usual.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any pairs of words like "beloved"/"belovèd", "learned"/"learnèd" that maintain a semantic difference to the present day?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20997/are-there-any-pairs-of-words-like-beloved-belov%c3%a8d-learned-learn%c3%a8d-that) Or this? [Are there any adjectives still using a grave accent to signify pronunciation of an extra syllable, like blessèd?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344455/are-%c3%a8d-adjectives-still-us%c3%a8d-words)

Comment: Neither one of those provides an answer to the second question. The answer to the first question is that both are correct, but not all participles/adjectives of this shape have the option of an extra syllable. The second question is much harder and probably is best answered by a list of idiomatic constructions.

Comment: Speaking personally (Though I'm British and old enough to have had a fairly traditional education, in which the James I, Authorised Version of the Bible, and Anglican hymns, played a part) if blessed was being employed as a verb (past tense or participle) I would pronounce it in two syllables. Used as an adjective, I would give it three syllables. Used as a noun - it could go either way.