# Pronunciation of "delivered yesterday", why "ed" not pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

In [this video](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/features/pronunciation/tims-pronunciation-workshop-ep-26), there is this sentence at 2:18:

> Your parcel should've been delivered yesterday.

I have listened to this sentence many times, it seems that the "ed" after delivered is not pronounced, what is this rule("ed" not pronounced) in English pronunciation?

Comment: I can clearly hear _delivered_. There is no rule about 'not pronouncing' the final 'd'.

Comment: Incidentally, as I've already said twice this morning, don't expect English spelling to represent English pronunciation. English learners have to learn the pronunciations and the spellings separately, because there are no consistent rules.

Comment: [Are there any pairs of words like _beloved_ and _belovèd_, _learned_ and _learnèd_, that ...?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20997/are-there-any-pairs-of-words-like-beloved-belov%c3%a8d-learned-learn%c3%a8d-that) might be helpful. It might even be a duplicate, but DialFrost's answer here brings out a salient point.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, he **did** pronounce out the "ed", it was just that he was reading it a bit quickly so it is easy to miss.

> According to [Guinlist - mishearing of english](https://guinlist.wordpress.com/tag/mishearing-of-english/):
>
> > The -ed ending could also fail to be heard as a result of the fact that it involves a “plosive” consonant (/d/ or /t/). Such consonants are often only half pronounced at the end of a word. They are pronounced most clearly when the next word begins with a vowel (e.g. dropped out, removed everything), and they are especially likely to be reduced before another (different) plosive (e.g. passed behind, argued convincingly) or at the end of a sentence.