# Are -èd adjectives still usèd words?

Tags: etymology, orthography, suffixes, syllables, diacritics

The distinction between the words **blessèd** (/ˈblɛsəd/) and **blessed** (/blɛst/) (see [Grammarbook](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/uncategorized/pronouncing-the-word-blessed)) appears to be wearing thin in modern language, possibly due to reduced accent usage and its resultant lack of different pronunciation between the two terms.

Wiktionary refers to the word as

> poetic, dated

And most damningly of all as an

> Alternative form of blessed (verb)

While I understand that little usage of terms such as blessèd and cursèd cause them to get blurred with their verb counterparts, some adjectives like *naked*, *talented*, *sacred* are still used, always written without the accent. In some legal and [political circles](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201011/cmhansrd/cm110713/debtext/110713-0003.htm)†, *learnèd* is still used for specific traditional purposes but it is now starting to fade.

### What is the history behind the distinction in pronunciation?

The reason why some of these words are pronounced with /əd/ is explained by the answers to this question: "[Why pronunciation of “Crooked” is “Crook-ked”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122652)"

David G said:

> If the normal form of the word (*crook*, *twist*) ends in *t* or *d*,
>   the -ed is enunciated (such as *wanted* or *bedded*).

This explains the pronunciation of *talented,* but not that of *naked, sacred,* or *blessed.* The pronunciation of *naked* is however explained by [coleopterist's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/97042/184766)  to this question: [Where does “wicked” get its /ɪd/ from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97037)

> According to [A Critical Pronouncing Dictionary and Expositor of the
>   English Language](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/uncategorized/pronouncing-the-word-blessed), 1839,
>
> > The adjectives *naked, wicked, picked (pointed), booked, crooked, forked, tusked, tressed, and wretched*, **are not derived from verbs,
> >     and are therefore pronounced in two syllables**. The same may be
> >     observed of *scabbed, crabbed, chubbed, stubbed, shagged, snagged,
> >     ragged, scrubbed, dogged, rugged, scragged, hawked, jagged*; to which
> >     we may add, the solemn pronunciation of *stiff-necked*; and these when
> >     formed into nouns with the addition of *ness*, preserved the *ed* in a
> >     distinct syllable, as *wickedness, scabbedness, raggedness*, &c.

However, the answers to "[Pronunciation of "Blessed"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6976/pronunciation-of-blessed)" don't describe the historical origin of the different pronunciations of this word as adjective and verb form.

### What is the history behind writing these words with accents?

How common was it in the past to write these words with grave accents, and in what contexts did people do this?  There has already been a question about the use of this accent in Shakespeare's work: "[Are there any pairs of words like “beloved”/“belovèd”, “learned”/“learnèd” that maintain a semantic difference to the present day?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20997)" But it's not clear from that if Shakespeare's original manuscripts use it, or if it something that's been added to modern editions to help readers find out the meter.

---

**Why have these words generally lost their accents?**

**Has this then lead on to them losing their differing pronunciations?**

**Finally, should one use a grave accent (è) here or should one just let context dictate pronunciation?**

<sub><sup>*†Interestingly, Hansard don't include accents at all, even when one looks back into the 18th and 19th century records. This may, however, be a result of typewriting and modernising of the records.*</sup></sub>

Comment: Related: [Pronunciation of “Blessed”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6976), [Are there any pairs of words like “beloved”/“belovèd”, “learned”/“learnèd” that maintain a semantic difference to the present day?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20997), [Where does “wicked” get its /ɪd/ from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97037) (this explains the pronunciation of "naked")

Comment: I feel like the most interesting part of this question is actually one of the unstated assumptions, so I'd like if you made it explicit: *How common was it in the past to write these words with grave accents, and in what contexts did people do this?* I.e. was it limited to poetry? Did Shakespeare's original manuscripts use it, or is it something that's added to modern editions to help readers find out the meter? You seem to be assuming that all these words started out being written with grave accents all the time, but I don't see how you know this. Why not ask about it?

Comment: Related and possibly useful links: 1) http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/03/diacritics-just-passe/ - 2) https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:About_Middle_English 3) http://www.hornetranslations.com/diacriticsenca.shtml 4) https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/documents/Diacritical.pdf

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44403/discussion-on-question-by-bladorthinthegrey-are-ed-adjectives-still-used-words).

Comment: Note that 'blessed' is the past tense of 'to bless', while 'bless-ed' (with accent) is the perfect/passive participle.

Comment: @AmI Yes, that was included in the opening sentence of the question. I presumed that people knew the difference but I nevertheless included a link to a source to explain the difference if people were un-aware

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't followed that parenthetical link.  I'm not qualified, but re your last 3 questions: our alphabet was simplified by losing accents; yes, pronunciation tends to the un-accented (at different rates); context is what we use to distinguish the forms, but additional marks make sense when there is no context.

Comment: The British charity **Help the Aged** founded in 1961 was originally pronounced 'Help the Agèd' by most people but by the time it merged with Age Concern to form Age UK in 2008 many younger people were calling it 'Help the Aged' with an unstressed final syllable. Perhaps this is because the stressed final syllable is becoming less familiar. This is a shame because the difference between agèd (old person) and aged (matured alcoholic drink); learnèd and learned etcetera is immensely valuable. Perhaps another argument for introducing accents and other marks into English spelling.

Comment: @BoldBen The two syllable version is NOT stressed on the last syllable!

Comment: @tchrist Perhaps its  a BrE/USE difference but TV adverts for Help the Aged always used to stress the second syllable. They just don't do TV any more.

Comment: @BoldBen No, he's right; it's "_ay_ jid" not "ay _jid_"

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Yeah, see what you mean. What I was getting at was that a lot of people now say Help the Ag'd  as in what happens to wine not Help the Ay jid which is what happens to people.

Comment: For *blessed / blessèd*, I wonder if the Sermon on the Mount is the source. I've only heard "blessèd are the poor in spirit" (Matt 5:3), no matter the version (KJV, NIV) or the speaker (AmE, BrE). In the same ecclesiastical context, this song, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTpTQ4kBLxA , by BrE singer / songwriter Matt Redman, sings *Blessèd be your name.*

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the original spelling in Shakespeare's sonnets, he was somewhat inconsistent. But he never used an accent, and he generally used *belov'd* for the two-syllable pronunciation (which the OP spells *beloved*) and *beloved* for the three-syllable pronunciation (which the OP spells *belovèd*).

It's not clear to me that there was ever any time when the accents were usually included in normal prose (as opposed to poetry, where accents were used to make sure it was pronounced as intended). I've checked samples of the phrase *learned man* from the 17th to the 19th centuries in Google books, and I haven't found any accent marks in prose.

For Shakespeare, there is a website that gives the original spelling for all the sonnets (click on the link and scroll down until you find it).

See [Sonnet CL:](http://www.shakespeares-sonnets.com/sonnet/150)

> If thy vnworthineſſe raiſd loue in me,
>      More worthy I to be belou'd of thee.

(note that he leaves out the apostrophe in rais'd.)

Also see [Sonnet CXXVIII,](http://www.shakespeares-sonnets.com/sonnet/128) which uses both *blessed* and *blest* in the original spelling.

And also [Sonnet II](http://www.shakespeares-sonnets.com/sonnet/2), which uses *gaz'd, totter'd, askt* and *deserv'd* in the original spelling.

Comment: *But he never used an accent* - I have seen Shakespeare plays and sonnets written *with* accentuation (in admittedly sparse and random place), is this just inserted by modern books?

Comment: These are inserted by modern editors so you will pronounce the words with the number of syllables Shakespeare used. (Otherwise the verse wouldn't scan.)

Comment: Interesting, do they also covert his *belov'd* into 'beloved'.

Comment: It probably depends on the modern-day editor.