# "Cursed" as two syllables in poetry

Tags: poetry, syllables

While the normal pronunciation of "cursed" is in one syllable, I have seen it used as a two-syllable word, "curs-ed". The Cambridge dictionary lists this pronunciation as an alternative in UK only: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cursed

Is the two-syllable version valid for use in modern poetry, or is it restricted to real or simulated Early Modern text, like thee/thou usually are?

Comment: Related: [Are -èd adjectives still usèd words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344455)

Comment: As a general rule, you can do pretty much anything in poetry and lyrics.  It's artistic license, a get-out-of-jail-free card to violate English rules.

Comment: As adjectives, both _cursed_ and _blessed_ are often voiced as two-syllable words. As past tense verbs, however, they are almost always voiced as one-syllable words.