# Is it possible for a word to have multiple different syllable counts? If so what is an example?

Tags: pronunciation, syllables

to further clarify, for example is it possible to have one word that has one pronunciation that is 2 syllables and at the same time the exact same word has another pronunciation that is 3 syllables

Comment: like gnu: guh-noo or g'nu?

Comment: Very close to the trivia category. And asking for a list is certainly off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth really I just wanted a simple yes or no answer since I couldn't find a definitive answer from searching online. (maybe I'm just bad at searching) I only asked for examples as proof that its actually possible

Comment: It's well known that certain words have alternative pronunciations; a look on virtually any page of any dictionary will confirm this. Some particular cases where the dictionaries disagree might well constitute valid queries on ELU. But I can't see examining a subclass where number of syllables differs as being helpful to many people. [Are adjectives ending in the syllable -ed still used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344455/are-%C3%A8d-adjectives-still-us%C3%A8d-words/349195#349195) was a related but valid enquiry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are English words that can be pronounced with more than one syllable count.

For example, [comfortable](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/comfortable) has two pronunciations listed in Collins. One has three syllables, another has four:

> (ˈkʌmftəbəl  , ˈkʌmfətəbəl  )

[Extraordinary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extraordinary) is listed with four, five, and six syllable pronunciations in Oxford Online:

> /ɪkˈstrɔːd(ə)n(ə)ri//ˌɛkstrəˈɔːdɪn(ə)ri//ɛkˈstrɔːd(ə)n(ə)ri/

Each of these are different pronunciations of the same word, not homonyms.

Comment: And [extraordinary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extraordinary) can be pronounced with four, five, or six syllables.

Comment: That's a very clear example, @PeterShor.  I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Consider [*library*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/library), for which ODO has two pronunciations, one with 2 syllables, the other with 3:

> /ˈlʌɪbri/ /ˈlʌɪbrəri/

Comment: That's [ˈlaɪbɹeɹi]  where I come from, which features an [ʌɪ] vs [aɪ] distinction due to Canadian raising (compare how the diphthong in  *tight* differs from that in *died* when said by nearly any native speaker from North America, not just in Canadians) and has monophthong /e/ instead of /eɪ/, especially before [ɹ]. We don’t reduce that next syllable the way the English do in *medicine, secretary, library*.  But *library* has other common (“mis-”)pronunciations due to [*r* dissimilation](http://web.csulb.edu/~nhall2/dissimilation_draft.pdf).